# android update play store

Tags: android, google-play, updates

I have a private app which is not and will not be released on the Google Play store.

I need a means to upgrade the app whenever an update is out, is there a library that will make it easier for me to push Over-the-air(OTA) updates from my server?

I am looking for the simplest solution. So far on my search I have not found any helpful results.

Comment: We went the super easy way and emailed the users an update link when available. Is this an option?

Comment: Our customers are busy and should not have to be concerned with links. It should just be an automated process apart from the user interaction to click though the steps.

Comment: Have you read into the native Android notifications? I don't know if a library will get a lot easier than that while still providing flexibility and power. May be a library out there but I haven't ever used one.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of would be to have a PHP which does a DB lookup. Each time you release a new version, you store this new version. Then your web server could have a scheduled task to run the PHP script which does the DB lookup and if a new version is found sends a notification to the user via Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) that your app listens for to display the notification.

Simpler solution, if you don't want to worry about using GCM, a PHP script again which your Android app could post to, say each day, and the PHP script does a lookup and returns if there is a new version and the URL to the new version that your app can then ask the user if they want to download the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the app on the Google Play Store, but not have it available to the public by using the alpha/beta users framework. You will have to create a Google Group for your app so that users/clients can install the app and receive OTA updates whenever you push an update to your google play developer account.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: I have looked into this, the problem is that each user will need to have a google account, and this is impractical for the execution of this app.